# Google Drive Url System Design

Tags: google-drive-api, scalability, system-design, google-drive-shared-drive

I noticed this behavior on Google Drive.

When a link is created for a file on Google Drive, the link is valid until the file is deleted.

Moving the file to another folder(s) does not affect the behavior of url.

I will like to understand how they achieved this at scale.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behavior when moving files to another folder within your google drive. This is because a google file URL is usually composed of the following:

- product domain
  [image]
- product
  [image]
- document Id
  [image]

Therefore, moving the file to another folder within the google drive will not affect the file URL because file path is not included in the URL format.

### References:

1. [Google Sheets API Overview](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts)
2. [Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/overview)

Comment: Thank you for you response, how is the folder structure managed?

Comment: You can manage folder structure using `Drive API`. You can create and populate folders,search for specific files and folders in the drive API. You can further explore managing files and folders here (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-files). Also you can manually organize and manage your files in the drive interface, please see this link for more details. (https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375091?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=)